# How to downgrade IE 11 to a previous iteration version of IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11

We have an application with clientside functionality that differs between IE 11 (version 11.1045.10586.0) and IE 11 (version 11.0.9600.18763).
How, if at all, is it possible to downgrade the specific IE version to a lower iterated version?

And I'm sure most are going to say, "download Chrome", but unfortunately that is not possible since the user base are VERY old school